# How to customize the submit button rendering?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using symfony 2.4 and I need to set my own theme for just the submit button within a form. I was already able to customize the way input fields are rendered, the following code is working.

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    {% if help is defined %}
        <span class="help">{{ help }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

**Question:** Which block do I need to override to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the [How to customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) section of the documentation. The submit button related blocks that you should override in order to customise your form's button are `{% block submit_widget %}` and `{% block button_widget %}` depending on the level of customisation you want to introduce.

Check the [form_div_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) code to fully understand the default implementation of those helpers.

**Good to know,**

- [Buttons support in Forms added to Symfony 2.3](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-buttons-support-in-forms).

Comment: Additionally, look for `{% block button_row %}` to customise the row output, took me a long while to work this out.

Comment: Thank you @contrebis Poor documentation is poor :( http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html Makes no mention of `block button_row`